# Azure B2C verify username and password

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-b2c

I'm working on some *webapis*. With **B2CGraphClient** I can create an user, update or delete it.

My problem is how I can verify username and password. I read [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations) about it but this case is not covered.

### Scenario

From an app the user sends its credentials (username / password). This credentials are stored in Azure B2C. I should call B2C and pass to it this credentials and receive if the user is valid and authenticated or not.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, Azure AD B2C doesn't have any direct support for this.

However, work to [support for the Resource Owner Password Credentials flow in Azure AD B2C](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/13817784-add-support-for-resource-owner-password-credential) is in-progress.

This new feature will enable apps to collect a user credential and POST it to the B2C tenant for validation.

**5 Oct 20: UPDATE**

Support for the Resource Owner Password Credentials flow has been implemented for Azure AD B2C's [built-in flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc?tabs=app-reg-ga) and [custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/ropc-custom?tabs=app-reg-ga).

Comment: Hi @Chris ,  is what Enrico asked available now? Too much misleading information on the internet.

Comment: Hi @DCodes I have added the doc links to the above answer.

Comment: When I use an ROPC flow, where would my user credentials be stored?